# How to create a pie-chart with dtypes in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to create a pie-chart that would show amounts of each type of values in my database: i.e.

```
object : 8
float64: 4
int: 5
```

and put all this into a pie-chart.
How should I do it?

So far, I've managed only to call df.dtypes

```
Company              object
Product              object
TypeName             object
Inches              float64
ScreenResolution      int64
Width                 int64
Height                int64
Cpu                  object
Cpu speed           float64
Ram(GB)               int64
Memory(GB)            int64
Memory type          object
Gpu                  object
OpSys                object
Weight(kg)          float64
Price_euros         float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
df.dtypes.value_counts().plot(kind='pie')
plt.show()
```

[image]